# Unable to start activity ,android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table, while compiling: SELECT * FROM table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting this error and doing first time so any suggestions, why it is coming and how to resolve it.
From this link i didnt get any help **[android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException near DATABASE_TABLE_NAME syntax error(code:1) while compiling organizationSetup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717863/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-near-database-table-name-syntax-errorco)**

Database handler

```
        public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

            // All Static variables
            // Database Version
            private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

            // Database Name
            private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

            // Login table name
            private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";
            private static final String TABLE_TRACK = "track";
            // Login Table Columns names
            private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
            private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
            private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
            private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
            private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
            // Track Table Columns names
            private static final String KEY_UIDTRACK = "idtrack";
            private static final String KEY_DOCKETNO = "docketno";
            private static final String KEY_DEALERNAME = "dealername";
            private static final String KEY_CUSTOMERNAME = "customername";
            private static final String KEY_PCS = "pcs";
            private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS = "deliverstatus";
            private static final String KEY_REMARKS = "remarks";
            private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK = "created_at_track";

            public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            // Creating Tables
            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE," + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";


                String CREATE_TABLE_TRACK = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRACK + "("
                        + KEY_UIDTRACK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DOCKETNO
                        + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DEALERNAME + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_CUSTOMERNAME + " TEXT ," + KEY_PCS
                        + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS + " TEXT ,"
                        + KEY_REMARKS + " TEXT ," + KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK + " TEXT"
                        + ")";
                 db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
                 db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TRACK);
            }

            // Upgrading database
            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // Drop older table if existed
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TRACK);
                // Create tables again
                onCreate(db);
            }

            /**
             * Storing user details in database
             * */
            public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
                values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
                values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email

                // Inserting Row
                db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
                db.close(); // Closing database connection
            }

            /**
             * Storing AeyeTrack details in database
             * */
            public void addAeyeTrack(Integer idtrack, Integer docketno,
                    String dealername, String customername, Integer pcs,
                    String deliverstatus, String remarks, String created_at_track) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(KEY_UIDTRACK, idtrack); // idtrack
                values.put(KEY_DOCKETNO, docketno); // docketno
                values.put(KEY_DEALERNAME, dealername); // dealername
                values.put(KEY_CUSTOMERNAME, customername); // customername
                values.put(KEY_PCS, pcs); // pcs
                values.put(KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS, deliverstatus); // deliverstatus
                values.put(KEY_REMARKS, remarks); // remarks
                values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK, created_at_track); // created_at_track

                // Inserting Row
                db.insert(TABLE_TRACK, null, values);
                db.close(); // Closing database connection
            }

            /**
             * Getting update AeyeTrack data from database
             * */
            public boolean updateAeyeTrack(Integer idtrack, Integer docketno,
                    String dealername, String customername, Integer pcs,
                    String deliverstatus, String remarks, String created_at_track) {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(KEY_UIDTRACK, idtrack); // idtrack
                contentValues.put(KEY_DOCKETNO, docketno); // docketno
                contentValues.put(KEY_DEALERNAME, dealername); // dealername
                contentValues.put(KEY_CUSTOMERNAME, customername); // customername
                contentValues.put(KEY_PCS, pcs); // pcs
                contentValues.put(KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS, deliverstatus); // deliverstatus
                contentValues.put(KEY_REMARKS, remarks); // remarks
                contentValues.put(KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK, created_at_track); // created_at_track

                db.update("track", contentValues, "idtrack = ? ",
                        new String[] { Integer.toString(idtrack) });
                return true;
            }



            /**
             * Getting AeyeTrack data from database
             * */
            public HashMap<String, String> getAeyeTrackDetails() {
                HashMap<String, String> AeyeTrack = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TRACK;

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    AeyeTrack.put("idtrack", cursor.getString(1));
                    AeyeTrack.put("docketno", cursor.getString(2));
                    AeyeTrack.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
                    AeyeTrack.put("dealername", cursor.getString(4));
                    AeyeTrack.put("customername", cursor.getString(5));
                    AeyeTrack.put("pcs", cursor.getString(6));
                    AeyeTrack.put("deliverstatus", cursor.getString(7));
                    AeyeTrack.put("remarks", cursor.getString(8));
                    AeyeTrack.put("created_at_track", cursor.getString(9));
                }

                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                // return user
                return AeyeTrack;
            }

            /**
             * Getting user data from database
             * */
            public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
                HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
                String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
                // Move to first row
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
                    user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
                    user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
                    user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
                // return user
                return user;
            }

            /**
             * Getting user login status return true if rows are there in table
             * */
            public int getRowCount() {
                String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
                int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
                db.close();
                cursor.close();

                // return row count
                return rowCount;
            }

            /**
             * Re create database Delete all tables and create them again
             * */
            public void resetTables() {
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                // Delete All Rows
                db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
                db.delete(TABLE_TRACK, null, null);
                db.close();
            }

        }

    This is my filtered logcat for my app

    01-10 11:54:03.150: I/PGA(2997): New SOCKET connection: m.awl.aeyetrack (pid 2997, tid 2997)
        01-10 11:54:17.840: D/Button(2997): Login
        01-10 11:54:17.840: I/System.out(2997): Email -- >pk@gmail.com
        01-10 11:54:17.840: I/System.out(2997): Password-->123456
        01-10 11:54:17.850: I/System.out(2997): password  < === >  123456
        01-10 11:54:17.850: I/System.out(2997): email  < === >  pk@gmail.com
        01-10 11:54:17.850: I/System.out(2997): tag  < === >  login
        01-10 11:54:23.560: I/System.out(2997): Response ---> {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"110085","user":{"name":"poonam","email":"pk@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-01-03 12:42:27","updated_at":null}}
        01-10 11:54:23.560: I/System.out(2997): Response from Web Service -- >{"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"uid":"110085","user":{"name":"poonam","email":"pk@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-01-03 12:42:27","updated_at":null}}
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997): Error inserting uid=110085 email=pk@gmail.com name=poonam
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at com.awl.aeyetrack.utils.DatabaseHandler.addUser(DatabaseHandler.java:85)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at com.awl.aeyetrack.LoginActivity$1.onTaskCompleted(LoginActivity.java:156)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at com.awl.aeyetrack.utils.Controller$AsyncHttpRequest.onPostExecute(Controller.java:126)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at com.awl.aeyetrack.utils.Controller$AsyncHttpRequest.onPostExecute(Controller.java:1)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
        01-10 11:54:23.630: E/SQLiteDatabase(2997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: D/dalvikvm(2997): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so 0xb30aa270
        01-10 11:54:25.770: D/dalvikvm(2997): Added shared lib /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so 0xb30aa270
        01-10 11:54:25.770: D/dalvikvm(2997): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so 0xb30aa270, skipping init
        01-10 11:54:25.770: D/dalvikvm(2997): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so 0xb30aa270
        01-10 11:54:25.770: D/dalvikvm(2997): Added shared lib /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so 0xb30aa270
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'init' (wrong CL)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so' for 'init'
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_init)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_init__)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' for 'init'
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_init)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): Found 'Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_init' with dlsym - func=0xab81c600
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'create' (wrong CL)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so' for 'create'
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_create)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_create__)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' for 'create'
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_create)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): Found 'Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_create' with dlsym - func=0xab81c7d0
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'setConfig' (wrong CL)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so' for 'setConfig'
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_setConfig)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_setConfig__III)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' for 'setConfig'
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_setConfig)
        01-10 11:54:25.770: V/dalvikvm(2997): Found 'Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_setConfig' with dlsym - func=0xab81c740
        01-10 11:54:25.940: D/dalvikvm(2997): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1334K, 35% free 6689K/10243K, paused 10ms
        01-10 11:54:25.950: D/dalvikvm(2997): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so 0xb30aa270
        01-10 11:54:25.950: D/dalvikvm(2997): Shared lib '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' already loaded in same CL 0xb30aa270

        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'setFormat' (wrong CL)
        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so' for 'setFormat'
        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Image_setFormat)
        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Image_setFormat__Ljava_lang_String_2)
        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' for 'setFormat'
        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Image_setFormat)
dlsy
        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_scanImage)
        01-10 11:54:25.950: V/dalvikvm(2997): Found 'Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_ImageScanner_scanImage' with dlsym - func=0xab81dce0
        01-10 11:54:26.120: D/dalvikvm(2997): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 95K, 27% free 7957K/10755K, paused 0ms
        01-10 11:55:03.550: D/dalvikvm(2997): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so 0xb30aa270
        01-10 11:55:03.550: D/dalvikvm(2997): Shared lib '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' already loaded in same CL 0xb30aa270
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ retrieving /data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so OnLoad status
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ earlier OnLoad(/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so) okay
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'init' (wrong CL)
      dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_next)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_next__)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' for 'next'
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_next)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): Found 'Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_next' with dlsym - func=0xab81d100
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'getData' (wrong CL)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so' for 'getData'
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getData)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getData__)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' for 'getData'
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getData)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): Found 'Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getData' with dlsym - func=0xab81d340
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'getType' (wrong CL)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libiconv.so' for 'getType'
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getType)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getType__J)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ scanning '/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/lib/libzbarjni.so' for 'getType'
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): +++ calling dlsym(Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getType)
        01-10 11:55:03.550: V/dalvikvm(2997): Found 'Java_net_sourceforge_zbar_Symbol_getType' with dlsym - func=0xab81d4e0
        01-10 11:55:03.630: I/System.out(2997): Scanned Result--->122100138237
        01-10 11:55:03.690: I/dalvikvm(2997): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onNestedScrollAccepted, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onNestedScrollAccepted
        01-10 11:55:03.690: W/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11401: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onNestedScrollAccepted (Landroid/view/View;Landroid/view/View;I)V
        01-10 11:55:03.690: D/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
        01-10 11:55:03.690: I/dalvikvm(2997): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onStopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onStopNestedScroll
        01-10 11:55:03.690: W/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11407: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onStopNestedScroll (Landroid/view/View;)V
        01-10 11:55:03.690: D/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0000
        01-10 11:55:03.690: I/dalvikvm(2997): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged
        01-10 11:55:03.690: W/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11409: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged (I)V
        01-10 11:55:03.690: D/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
        01-10 11:55:03.690: I/dalvikvm(2997): Could not find method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.stopNestedScroll, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.setHideOnContentScrollEnabled
        01-10 11:55:03.690: W/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9088: Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout;.stopNestedScroll ()V
        01-10 11:55:03.690: D/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000e
        01-10 11:55:03.700: I/dalvikvm(2997): Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
        01-10 11:55:03.700: W/dalvikvm(2997): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11404: La
        01-10 11:55:03.740: I/System.out(2997): Got this Scanned Result From Intent-->122100138237
        01-10 11:55:03.740: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(2997): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: track, db=/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/databases/android_api
        01-10 11:55:03.740: D/AndroidRuntime(2997): Shutting down VM
        01-10 11:55:03.740: W/dalvikvm(2997): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2c6b180)
        01-10 11:55:03.740: D/AndroidRuntime(2997): procName from cmdline: com.awl.aeyetrack
        01-10 11:55:03.740: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.awl.aeyetrack
        01-10 11:55:03.740: D/AndroidRuntime(2997): file written successfully with content: com.awl.aeyetrack StringBuffer : ;com.awl.aeyetrack
        01-10 11:55:03.750: I/Process(2997): Sending signal. PID: 2997 SIG: 9
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.awl.aeyetrack/com.awl.aeyetrack.DashboardActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: track: , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM track
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        01-10 11:55:03.750: E/AndroidRuntime(2997): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: track: , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM track
```

Comment: are you sure track table is present and is created successfully onCreate?

Comment: just uninsital your application an then run your project again.

Comment: Uninstall application or increment db version.

Comment: @Milad and Shiva 01-10 12:23:01.510: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(3928): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table "track" has more than one primary key, db=/data/data/com.awl.aeyetrack/databases/android_api

Comment: Your syntax is wrong for a primary key over multiple columns. Also, you're missing a space between the `KEY_DOCKETNO` and `KEY_PCS` values, and the following `"INTEGER..."` for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in you have two primary keys in your CREATE_TABLE_TRACK  so just remove one of those to solve the problem. like this :

```
//just removed one of ypur primary keys
String CREATE_TABLE_TRACK = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TRACK + "("
                    + KEY_UIDTRACK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DOCKETNO
                    + " INTEGER ," + KEY_DEALERNAME + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_CUSTOMERNAME + " TEXT ," + KEY_PCS
                    + " INTEGER ," + KEY_DELIVERY_STATUS + " TEXT ,"
                    + KEY_REMARKS + " TEXT ," + KEY_CREATED_AT_TRACK + " TEXT"
                    + ")";
```

as @Mike M said you have some syntax errors in your code. I fixed them too.